# RobotFramework : catenate with FOR loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, automated-tests, robotframework

I am fairly new to using RobotFramework and trying format a string using Catenate, wondering if I can use FOR loop while formatting the string and the below is correct format? Any suggestion would be really appreciated, thanks!!!

```
${data}=    Catenate
...    {
...    "email_address": "${NewUserEmailID}",
...    "user_name": "${UserName}",
...    "roles": [
...    :FOR    ${roleId}, ${catID}, ${subcatID}    IN    @{role_id_list}, @{category_id_list}, @{subCat_id_list}
...    /    {
...    /    "role_id": ${roleId},
...    /    "categories": [{ "category_id": "${catID}" }],
...    /    "subcats":[{ "sub_category_id": "${subcatID}" }]
...    /    },
...    ],
...    "line_manager": "${LineManageID}",
...    "guest_user": ${GuestUser},
...    "guest_invitation_text":    "Invitation Text",
...    "guest_redirect_url":    "http://www.example.com/guest",
...    "organization_id":    1
...    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? ;) No, at least not in the way you hope it'll run - the loop will not execute, you'll just end up with the end string having ":FOR", "@{role_id_list}" etc in it.

Comment: You should implement a special catenate keyword for this in pure python.

Answer (score -1):

> wondering if I can use FOR loop while formatting the string

No, in the sense of the loop being executed, and appending the values of each iteration to the `Catenate` target. What will happen is you'll end up with the end string having ":FOR", "@{role_id_list}" etc in it.

But achieving what you want is not that hard - just have a loop that will construct the intermediate string, and append *that* within the  `Catenate`. Like this:

```
${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${EMPTY}    # initialize an empty string variable

:FOR    ${roleId}    ${catID}    ${subcatID}    IN ZIP    ${role_id_list}    ${category_id_list}    ${subCat_id_list}
/    ${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${roles array}{  # you append the target string to the end of the current value of the variable
/    ${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${roles array}"role_id": ${roleId},
/    ${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${roles array}"categories": [{ "category_id": "${catID}" }],
/    ${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${roles array}"subcats":[{ "sub_category_id": "${subcatID}" }]
/    ${roles array}=    Set Variable    ${roles array}},

# and now use it inside the Catenate
${data}=    Catenate
...    {
...    "email_address": "${NewUserEmailID}",
...    "user_name": "${UserName}",
...    "roles": [ ${roles array}
...    ],
...    "line_manager": "${LineManageID}",
...    "guest_user": ${GuestUser},
...    "guest_invitation_text":    "Invitation Text",
...    "guest_redirect_url":    "http://www.example.com/guest",
...    "organization_id":    1
...    }
```

As you notice, the syntax for iterating over more than one list is a bit different - one needs to use the [`IN ZIP`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-zip-loop) (that comes from/is analogues to python's `zip()` function).